# Сбор данных подписчиков приложения вконтакте

Tags: рассылка, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте.

Есть приложение вктонтакте. У него более 12.000 подписчиков. Хотелось бы сделать информационные рассылки от приложения. Как возможно собрать базу подписчиков приложения.

Может быть есть уже готовые решение прошу помогите, а то я не сведущ в API соц.сетей.

Comment: насколько я знаю, контактик через API не дает доступа к емейлам

Comment: никто и не говорил про емайлы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока VK API не дает таких возможностей. Но способы есть.

1. Начать немедленно собирать ID пользователей, которые заходят в приложение. Он есть в параметрах загрузки приложения.
2. Перебором найти всех остальных. Да, циклом, долго, но если сузить возможную аудиторию, то есть вероятность сделать это быстрее. Например, какие переходы? зацепиться за одного-двух пользователей и идти по его друзьям.
3. Неизвестный автор третьего способа заметил особенность: если загрузить страницу приложение неавторизированным (или в анонимной вкладке) будет маленький список аватарок из установивших. При каждой загрузке уже иные люди. Как вариант для зацепки.